# Resizing Drawn Image at Center

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, resize, picturebox

I want to use a track bar to re-size an image which is being drawn in the `.._Paint` event.

So far I've loaded an Image from file into a Bitmap called `original`. Now I have another Bitmap called 'cropped' which stores part of the original image.

```
Bitmap original = new Bitmap(spriteSheet);
RectangleF srcRect = new RectangleF(ip.x, ip.y, ip.width, ip.height);
Bitmap cropped = original.Clone(srcRect, original.PixelFormat);
```

I have a picturebox called `pb_preview` which draws the cropped image like so:

```
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
RectangleF rc = new RectangleF(pb_preview.Height / 2, pb_preview.Width / 2, zoomSlider.Value * cropped.Width, zoomSlider.Value * cropped.Height);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(cropped, rc);
```

In my trackbars changed value event, I invalidate `pb_preview` so everytime I change the value, the `pb_preview` will draw the image at a larger value.

Problem is that each time I change the trackbar's value, the image doesn't resize on the center, instead it resizes but each time it resizes it goes a little to the left until the maximum resized image is out of frame.

Comment: can you post the code where you invalidate the `PictureBox` ?

Comment: @VishnuPrasad I invalidate at Trackbar Scroll event and Right after I create the cropped bitmap, underneath that.

Comment: are you creating cropped Bitmap every time then? if so, does `ip` object members value change in that time? . It appears that your cropped image size is scaled disproportionately with the `pb_preview` picturebox size.

Comment: @VishnuPrasad I managed to solve it, will be posting solution soon

Comment: @VishnuPrasad Thanks for the effort :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find another question in regards to resizing and came across this function:

```
private Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap b, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the value changed event for the Trackbar, I do:

```
pb_preview.Image = ResizeBitmap(cropped, zoomSlider.Value * cropped.Width, zoomSlider.Value * cropped.Height);
```